# Plone 4.3 template can not get new user Role

Tags: plone-4.x

```
    in custom edit template i display user roles:

    <metal:block fill-slot="widgets">
                    <tal:globals tal:define="
                        portal_membership nocall: context/portal_membership;
                        userRoles python: portal_membership.getAuthenticatedMember().getRoles();
     ">
....
    <p tal:content="userRoles "></p>
```

from /@@usergroup-userprefs i added, removed roles to a test user, but when logged in as test user i see the same roles! Test user roles changed only when i restart client by runnning

bin/client1 restart; bin/client1 stop; bin/client1 fg

Could anyone give advice? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

add/remove roles via
/acl_users/portal_role_manager

as you said [here](https://community.plone.org/t/plone-4-3-template-can-not-get-new-user-role/11240/2) :)